# Как включить атрибуты тега в блок jinja2?

Tags: python, html, bootstrap, flask, jinja2

Имеем код

'''
`<body class="text-center">`

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

`</body>`
'''

Как в блок включить class="text-center"? А link'и? Стоит ли делать шаблонизацию стилей или есть другой способ? Пытаюсь подружить bootstrap и jinja2, или не стоит заморачиваться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пытаюсь в шаблонизатор jinja2 добавить стили CSS. Чтобы дочерние страницы наследовали блоки вместе со стилями, если они оказывается вне границ блоков